# How implement route params in an angular application?

Tags: angular

I have an angular application with several modules and I have implemented the router with different urls loading different components. One of my urls is a route param with :id ...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:SplashComponent},
  {path:'start', loadChildren:'./guest/guest.module#GuestModule'},
  {path:'login', loadChildren:'./admin/admin.module#AdminModule'},
  {path:":id", component:GuestHomepageComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

You're supposed to be able to go to mysitename.com/username to bring up a users profile.

With this solution if I go to my-site.com/username, then the site routes to the users profile as desired. Although if I go to my-site.com and click on a link that routes to one of the modules then angular views this as the routeparam and tries to route to the users profile instead of the route designated for the component to be loaded by the route of that module.

How do you avoid this problem? Is it possible for angular to ignore the other routes of the application designated in the RouterConfigs for their respective modules when going to my-site.com/username, and then use the RouterConfigs for the routes designated in those modules?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the routerLink you clicked. You have a route with empty path (`''`) with no children and no redirect. Such routes should have `pathMatch: 'full'` added.

Comment: "and click on a link that routes to one of the modules then angular views this as the routeparam". I think this is because none of the previous routes match and then the one with the parameter is used, because it matches every route with one segment.